# Form Submission - Using a function within a PHP class to process the form

Tags: php, html, forms, class, function

I am using three files on a project: `index.php`, `class.php`, and `styles.css`.

All my functions reside within a php class in the class.php file:

```
<?php

class Club
{
    //Private Data
    private $HostName;      //typically "localhost"
    private $UserId;
    private $Password;
    private $DBName;
    private $Con;           //MySQL Connection
    //Public Methods
    //Constructor
    public function __construct($host = NULL, $uid = NULL, $pw = NULL, $db = NULL)
    {
        $this->HostName = $host;
        $this->UserID = $uid;
        $this->Password = $pw;
        $this->DBName = $db;

        //Connect to Database
        $this -> Con = mysqli_connect($host, $uid, $pw, $db);
        if(mysgli_connect_errno($this -> Con))
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL; " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

    }
    //Destructor
    public function __destruct()
    {
        //Close connection
        mysqli_close($this -> Con);
    }
    public function DisplayMembers()
    {
            }
            function DisplayAbout()
    {
            }
            function DisplayRegistrationForm()
    {
        echo("<h2>Become a Club Member</h2>

        <form name='register' method='post' action=''>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width='80px'>
                            <label>First Name: </label>
                        </td>
                        <td width='300'>
                            <input id='firstname' type='text' name='firstname' value='' required/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Last Name: </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id='lastname' type='text' name='lastname' value='' required/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Your Email: </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id='email' type='text' name='email' value='' required/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Gender: </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id='gender' type='radio' name='gender' value='male'>Male<br />
                            <input id='gender' type='radio' name='gender' value='female'>Female
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Interested in: </label>
                        </td>
                        <td id='check'>
                            <span style='font-weight: bold;'>Check All that Apply:</span><br />
                            <input id='interests' type='checkbox' name='interests[]' value='Pizza Party'>Pizza Party<br />
                            <input id='interests' type='checkbox' name='interests[]' value='Joining Study Groups'>Joining Study Groups<br />
                            <input id='interests' type='checkbox' name='interests[]' value='Visiting Employer Sites'>Visiting Employer Sites<br />
                            <input id='interests' type='checkbox' name='interests[]' value='Participating in Programming Competition'>Participating in Programming Competitions<br />
                            <input id='interests' type='checkbox' name='interests[]' value='Building Games'>Building Games<br />
                            <input id='interests' type='checkbox' name='interests[]' value='Becoming an Officer of the Club'>Becoming an Officer of the Club
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='2' style='text-align: center;'>
                            <input id='submit' type='submit' name='submit' value='Sign Up'/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>    
        </form>");
    }
            function ProcessRegistrationForm()
    {
            }
            private function Get_Members_From_DB()
    {
            }
            private function Get_Members_Interests_From_DB($MemberEmail)
    {
            }
            private function Get_Interests_Types_From_DB()
    {
            }
 }
 ?>
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what to put in the action section of the form portion in order to use the `ProcessRegistrationFunction()` within the class.  So basically, the `DisplayRegistrationForm()` is called in the `index.php` file in a `div`, and then I want it to be processed by the `ProcessRegistrationFunction()` within the class. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to do this.

Comment: Well, for starters it is `__construct` not `_construct`

Comment: Where do you call `DisplayRegistrationForm`?

Comment: I call DisplayRegistrationForm in the index.php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can send your form data to index.php itself and than send whatever data to your process function. the best way to implement this will be is to change your form to collect data as an array.

here `myFormArray` will store all the information about the form

```
<input id='firstname' type='text' name='myFormArray[firstname]' value='' required/>

<input id='lastname' type='text' name='myFormArray[lastname]' value='' required/>
```

this value can be accessed in your index.php when you submit the form

so in your index.php

```
 if(isset($_POST["submit"]){
    $formData = $_POST["myFormArray"]; // dont forget to sanitize any post data
   //than you can call your class function and pass this data
   $class = new class();
   $class->ProcessRegistrationFunction($formData);
 }
```

your ProcessRegistrationFunction($data) will now have all the data in an array form..

you can iterate over it and fet the individual values

Note: there are lot of syntax error in your class.. also there is better way to implement this class.. for one you should always avoid html code inside your classs..

Dins

Comment: So do I put anything into the action field?

Comment: you can put index.php or just leave it blank.. in both case it will submit to index.php

Comment: The if statement gives me a fatal code no matter where I put it:  Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Comment: Ok, I figured out the fatal code. But now I am having trouble getting this to go into my database.

Comment: I update this in a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271144/php-website-switching-from-xml-style-data-to-mysql-with-class-file

Answer (score 0):

while typing type correctly so u can avoid unwanted errors

```
 'if(mysgli_connect_errno($this -> Con))'
```

it should be

```
 'if(mysqli_connect_errno($this -> Con))'
```

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be in the comments or an edit request. If you don't/didn't have enough rep, oh well.