# PHP Form to MySQL - Array[] into MySQL Issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I am working on a website that is supposed to allow Club Member registration.  The information from a form is supposed to be stored into a MySQL database.  I have already accomplished this with storing and reading from a XML style text file, but now I must convert it to MySQL.  The following is code from part of the `index.php`:

```
    <div id="rightcol">
    <?php
        include_once("Membership_Class.php");

        $myClub = new Club("Localhost", "AMemberUser", "Pass123Word", "info_club");

        if(isset($_GET['BodyContent']))
        {
            if($_GET['BodyContent'] == "about")
            {
                $myClub -> DisplayAbout();
            }
            else if($_GET['BodyContent'] == "register")
            {
                $myClub -> DisplayRegistrationForm();
            }
            else if($_GET['BodyContent'] == "processregistration")
            {
                $myClub -> ProcessRegistrationForm();
            }
            else if($_GET['BodyContent'] == "members")
            {
                $myClub -> DisplayMembers();
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

The next part is from my `Membership_Class.php` file:

```
function DisplayRegistrationForm()
    {
        echo("<h2>Become a Club Member</h2>

        <form name='register' method='post' action='Assign5_Solution.php?BodyContent=processregistration'>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width='80px'>
                            <label>First Name: </label>
                        </td>
                        <td width='300'>
                            <input id='firstname' type='text' name='firstname' value='' required/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Last Name: </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id='lastname' type='text' name='lastname' value='' required/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Your Email: </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id='email' type='text' name='email' value='' required/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Gender: </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id='gender' type='radio' name='gender' value='male'>Male<br />
                            <input id='gender' type='radio' name='gender' value='female'>Female
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Interested in: </label>
                        </td>
                        <td id='check'>
                            <span style='font-weight: bold;'>Check All that Apply:</span><br />
                            <input id='interests' type='checkbox' name='interests[]' value='1'>Pizza Party<br />
                            <input id='interests' type='checkbox' name='interests[]' value='2'>Joining Study Groups<br />
                            <input id='interests' type='checkbox' name='interests[]' value='3'>Visiting Employer Sites<br />
                            <input id='interests' type='checkbox' name='interests[]' value='4'>Participating in Programming Competitions<br />
                            <input id='interests' type='checkbox' name='interests[]' value='5'>Building Games<br />
                            <input id='interests' type='checkbox' name='interests[]' value='6'>Becoming an Officer of the Club
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='2' style='text-align: center;'>
                            <input id='submit' type='submit' name='submit' value='Sign Up'/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>    
        </form>");
    }

    function ProcessRegistrationForm()
    {   
        $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $interests = $_POST['interests'];

        if(!isset($_POST['firstname']) || !isset($_POST['lastname']) || !isset($_POST['email']) ||
            ($_POST['firstname']) == '' || ($_POST['lastname']) == '' || ($_POST['email']) == '')
        {
            echo("Please enter your first / last name and email.");
        }   
        else
        {
            echo("<h2>Results</h2>");
            echo("<div id='results'>");
            echo $fname; 
            echo("<br />");
            echo $lname; 
            echo("<br />");
            echo $email;
            echo("<br />");
            echo $gender;
            echo("<br />");
            foreach($interests as $likes)
            {
                echo $likes . "<br />";
            }
            echo("<p style='font-weight: bold;'>Your data has been saved! We will contact you soon!</p>");
            echo("</div>");
        }

        $myClub = new Club("localhost","A340User","Pass123Word","info_club");

        $date = date("Y/m/d");

        $sql="INSERT INTO member
                    (`FirstName`,`LastName`,`Gender`,`Email`,`MemberSince`)
                VALUES
                    ('$fname','$lname','$gender','$email','$date');";

        $result = mysqli_query($this->Con,$sql);
        if($result == true) 
        {
            echo "Successful Insert<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error Inserting class" . mysqli_error($this->Con) ." <br />";
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($interests); $i++)
        {
            $interest = $interests[$i];

            $sql="INSERT INTO member_interests
                        (`Email`,`InterestID`)
                    VALUES
                        ('$email',$interest);";
        }

        $result = mysqli_query($this->Con,$sql);
        if($result == true) 
        {
            echo "Successful Insert<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error Inserting class" . mysqli_error($this->Con) ." <br />";
        }
```

Right now I have gotten this to post to my database, but when I check multiple interests in the form data when I am testing it, it only posts one of the interests I check to the member_interests table.  Obviously I have the interests[] array wrong somewhere, or the loop.

My database is called info_club with three tables: `interest_type`, `member`, and `member_interests`. The user email is the `key id`.  In the interest_type table there is two columns, `InterestID`, and `InterestDescription`. In the member table there is `Email`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Gender`, and `MemberSince`. In my `member_interests` table there is an `Email` and `InterestID` columns.

I need to find out how to get multiple interests into the member_interests table.

Comment: Don't use spaces.  `$this -> HostName` should be always written as `$this->hostname`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php

Comment: Why are you creating a new Club object for every row retrieved from the database? Seems to me that you should be creating a Member object with the retrieved row and from there have methods for getting interests, etc. The way you have it now is very confusing.

Comment: I didn't think the spaces mattered like other languages. I was doing it to keep it cleaned up.  And I am not even sure what you mean jraede, like I said, I am kind of new to MySQL.  I was trying to use the same model from a previous project. I probably do have it wrong. But getting it right is what I need guidance for.

Comment: Test the components separately. Put a filled `insert` statement at the SQL command window for starters. Figure out what the error is that's not getting reported properly

Comment: I am getting no errors when I am using the SQL command window. The same commands insert rows perfectly in phpAdmin. Of course I cannot use the php variables, but when I sub them for actual data, it works fine. So it has to be there in the variables or php code, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Edited my code above. UPDATE: I now have the form submitting to the database, but I cannot get multiple items checked in the Interests section of my form to post to the member_interests table. I need help with the array or loops to get this accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I switched the `$result = mysqli_query($this->Con,$sql);` line into the for loop and it works well inserting into the database. So simple. So the correct code above is:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($interests); $i++)
        {
            $interest = $interests[$i];

            $sql="INSERT INTO member_interests
                        (`Email`,`InterestID`)
                    VALUES
                        ('$email',$interest);";

            $result = mysqli_query($this->Con,$sql);
        }
```