# PHP mail with attachment not working as a Shortcode

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So I've been asked to create a form that once filled in sends an email to my client with the form entry, this must include a .csv file attachment with the included data.

Initially I tested this by hardcoding it to a plain page.

```
   <form class="main-form" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li><div>Email: </div><input type="email" name="email" size="20" /></li>

            <br />
            <input type="submit">

            </ul>
        </form>

        <?php

            $email=$_REQUEST['email'];

            if ($email =="") {
                //Do nothing
            } else {

            $to = "mail@test.co.uk";
            $from = "test";


            $subject = "test";

            //Message Body
            $text = "test";

            //The Attachment
            $cr = "\n";
            $data = "Email"
            $data .= "$email". $cr;
            $fp = fopen('test.csv','a');
            fwrite($fp,$data);
            fclose($fp);

            $attachments[] = Array(
               'data' => $data,
               'name' => 'diploma_apprenticeship_form_sub.csv',
               'type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
            );


            //Generate a boundary string

            $semi_rand = md5(time());
            $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";


            //Add the headers for a file attachment


            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
                       "From: BRS\n" .
                       "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
                       " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";


            //Add a multipart boundary above the plain message


            $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
                      "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                      "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
                      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
                      $text . "\n\n";


            //Add attachments

            foreach($attachments as $attachment){
               $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($attachment['data']));
               $name = $attachment['name'];
               $type = $attachment['type'];

               $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                          "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
                          " name=\"{$name}\"\n" .
                          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
                          $data . "\n\n" ;
            }

            $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        }

            ?>
```

This works fine and emails the attachment exactly as I want. However they now want it as a shortcode so they can post it wherever in their wordpress build. So I've added the shortcode and posted the code into a php function which is called when wordpress detects `[form]`. But now it doesn't work.

```
function main_form() {

return <<<HTML
 <form class="main-form" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li><div>Email: </div><input type="email" name="email" size="20" /></li>

            <br />
            <input type="submit">

            </ul>
        </form>
 HTML;

 // Then rest of php as it was above
 }
```

The form outputs fine, but I no longer get an email. Initially I thought that the `$_REQUEST[];` wasn't getting the data but I set $email to a fixed string and it still doesn't work.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using a return statement before the rest of the PHP hence it was printing the HTML and exiting the function. By putting the return at the end of the function it now works!

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to something like this:

```
<form class="main-form" method="post" action="file.php">
```

You'll be redirected to "file.php" after your form will be submitted.

You can find a working example here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Why do I have to do that? Surely the php can be done on the same page?

Comment: On the action you can also call a method from the same file. In that case you will create a function in your file, and you'll use something like:  "if(isset($_POST["submit"]){" . You can find something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16269295/1564840